# Receive large files via WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I have an application that should receive large files, this is why I am using a `stream` parameter.

Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFile
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Upload?fileName={fileName}&requestType={requestType}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    FileMetadata Upload(string fileName, RequestType requestType, Stream stream);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public FileMetadata Upload(string fileName, RequestType requestType, Stream stream)
{
    var contract = GetContract(fileName, requestType, stream);
    ...
}

private static FileUploadRequest GetContract(string fileName, RequestType requestType, Stream content)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    content.CopyTo(ms);
    return new FileUploadRequest
    {
        Filename = fileName,
        RequestType = requestType,
        Content = ms.ToArray()
    };
}
```

But with stream I receive a trash info (boundary and so on), sample of transfered XML is:

```
--a288ea6c-376a-4c7e-9680-39199e34082c
Content-Disposition: form-data

<Doc> ... rest of XML
```

How can I tranfer a stream itself? Should I remove boundary on client side or truncate in on server one? Becuase this service should be used from JS too, and I don't know if it inludes such additional info or doesn't.

Client side sends a request like this:

```
public async Task<FileMetadata> Upload(string fileName, RequestType requestType, Stream stream)
{
    var requestUri = $"Upload?fileName={fileName}&requestType={requestType}";
    using (var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        requestContent.Add(new StreamContent(stream));
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileMetadata>(responseContent);
        }
    }
    throw new Exception();
}
```

It works fine with `HttpWebRequest`, but i'd like to use more modern apporach. I'm sure i'm doing something wrong, please advice:

```
public FileMetadata Upload(string fileName, RequestType requestType, Stream stream)
{
    var requestUri = $"Upload?fileName={fileName}&requestType={requestType}";
    var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(_client.BaseAddress, requestUri));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    request.ContentLength = stream.Length;
    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileMetadata>(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: just use `StreamContent` alone, without wrapping in `MultipardFormDataContent`. Code sample:

```
public async Task<FileMetadata> Upload(string fileName, RequestType requestType, Stream stream)
{
    var requestUri = $"Upload?fileName={fileName}&requestType={requestType}";
    var response = await _client.PostAsync(requestUri, new StreamContent(stream)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileMetadata>(responseContent);
    }
    throw new Exception();
}
```